# call a function from another class in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm still new to react I need help in calling a function from another class/file. Also I want to use the states from the class1 file.

in short, this are the codes:

**function in Class1**

```
endCall() {
    endCall(this.state.currentCallRoom);
    this.setState(
      {
        isCallOngoing: false,
        currentCallRoom: null,
        notification: null,
      },
      () => console.log("Call ended")
    );
  }
```

**div in Class2**

```
 <div className={s.IconContainer}>
              <IconButton className={s.topIcon} onClick={() => this.endCall()}>
                <CallEnd className={s.icon} style={{color: "red"}}/>
                <text className={s.text}>EndCall</text>
              </IconButton>
            </div>
```

does anyone have any idea how i can use the method from class1?

Comment: can you provide more code please. How does your render function look like. The simple answer is that you have to pass `endCall` to your `Class2` component. 

And also you are calling `endCall` as a recursive function so it doesn't look like it will ever set the new state and instead it's just an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't very clear. I suggest to move endCall function to class1 and class2's parent component, and also manage State in the parent component as well, then pass the function and any data you need as props to class1 and class2. Also suggest a readthrough of this article [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Hope this may help.

Comment: Can you add more code for better understanding since code snippet is not complete unable to answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import { foo_function } from './your-file-name'
```

move your function outside the class and import this way